# GWT Grid is not appearing with uiBinder

Tags: gwt, grid, uibinder

I have a 2 by 2 Grid in a project which is initialised using uiBuilder, however, the grid never appears on the page. The title and subheading appear fine. I've been struggling with this for days. Any advice is very much appreciated (this is my first gwt project). Thank you!

There are 3 files: Test.java, TaskSelect.java and TaskSelect.ui.xml

*Test.java***

```
package org.client;  
    import com.google.gwt.core.client.*;  
    import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.*;

    public class Test extends DeckPanel implements EntryPoint 
    {

    public void onModuleLoad()
    {
        Test t = new Test();
    TaskSelect taskselect = new TaskSelect();
    t.add(taskselect);
    t.showWidget(0);
        RootPanel.get().clear();
        RootPanel.get().add(t);
    }
}
```

****TaskSelect.java*****

```
package org.client;

    import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.*;
    import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
    import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.*;

    public class TaskSelect extends Composite {
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, TaskSelect> { }
    private static final Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);
    @UiField Button buttonA;
    @UiField Button buttonB;
    @UiField Button buttonC;
    @UiField Button buttonD;
    @UiField Grid mygrid;

    public TaskSelect() {
        initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}
```

****TaskSelect.ui.xml*****

```
<ui:UiBinder
  xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
  xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>

  <ui:style>
    .bigbutton {
    font-size: 24pt;
    width: 300px;
    height: 95px;
    }

    .h1 {
    font-size: 36pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    }

    .subheading {
    font-size: 24pt;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    }

    .panel {
    margin: auto;
    }
    </ui:style>
      <g:DockLayoutPanel unit='EM' addStyleNames='{style.panel}'>
    <g:north size='10'>
      <g:VerticalPanel addStyleNames='{style.panel}'>
        <g:Label addStyleNames='{style.h1}'>Title is here</g:Label>
        <g:Label addStyleNames='{style.subheading}'>Sub heading</g:Label>
      </g:VerticalPanel>
    </g:north>
    <g:center size='10'>
      <g:Grid ui:field='mygrid' addStyleNames='{style.panel}' cellSpacing='50'>
        <g:row>
          <g:customCell>
            <g:Button ui:field='buttonA'>Button A</g:Button>
          </g:customCell>
          <g:customCell>
            <g:Button addStyleNames='{style.bigbutton}' text='Button B' ui:field='buttonB' />
          </g:customCell>
        </g:row>
        <g:row>
          <g:customCell>
            <g:Button addStyleNames='{style.bigbutton}' text='Button C' ui:field='buttonC' />
          </g:customCell>
          <g:customCell>
            <g:Button addStyleNames='{style.bigbutton}' text='Button D' ui:field='buttonD' />
          </g:customCell>
        </g:row>
      </g:Grid>
    </g:center>
  </g:DockLayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height/width of the grid is set by the `DockLayoutPanel` as `DockLayoutPanel` automatically scales to fill the whole area. Check the documentation on the Layout widgets and see if you need `DockLayoutPanel` or `DockPanel`.

Anyway adding this to the `.panel` style should make it work:

```
height:100%;
```

Yes, it doesn't sound logical...

**-edit-**

And use `RootLayoutPanel.get()` instead of `RootPanel.get()`. This because you use a LayoutPanel.

Comment: I added that in to `.panel`, but the result is unchanged. I see the title and subheading, but not the grid in the center. I originally had a DockPanel, but GWT told me it was deprecated and I should use a DockLayoutPanel.

Comment: Yes, but also note that DockLayoutPanel is a layout panel and this requires special attention. Read upon it on the gwt documentation site: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#LayoutPanels. Probably why it's not working right now, is because to need to use `RootLayoutPanel.get()` and check you doctype.

Comment: You are a legend! Changing to RootLayoutPanel.xxx fixed it. Thank you very much!